# Why is the article before "He introduced roll film in 1884" omitted?

Tags: grammaticality

Why is "the" omitted before "roll film"?

Example: "In 1884 George Eastman of N.Y. introduced roll film...".

I have found this sentence in: "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland",  by Gina Clemens, Black Cat, 2013, p. 27. and on Wikipedia (roll film) I Have found a sentence where the article "the" before roll film is also omitted.

The problem is important for learners of English. I couldn't find a solution in my grammar books for very advanced learners of English, e.g.: A Practical English Grammar, A.J. Thomson and A.V. Martinet, Oxford University Press, 1986, 4th edition.

I need a grammar rule.

Comment: 'Roll film' describes the type of film that Eastman introduced, like 'gloss paint' or 'wholemeal bread' - 'film' is treated as an uncountable noun. The author could have said that he introduced 'the film roll' - treated as the name of an object.

Comment: Because it's a type of a thing, or a process, like moveable type. Whenever you see this, you should think **process or type** not individual object. I

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd case, because "film" can be countable or uncountable, depending on the situation in which it's used.  If I'm a film photographer, I don't go to the store to buy *a* film—I go to buy a *roll of* film (or five, if there's a cheap 5-pack available).  If I'm going to get a movie, however, I'll say that I'm going to get *a* film.  Since it appears we're talking about something involving the production of "film" as a medium here, and not "films" as in moving-picture productions, "film" is uncountable, and so it doesn't make sense to say that George Eastman introduced "the roll film."

In the end, therefore, it's not so much that you can remove "the" from countable nouns in this context (although you can do that in cooking recipes, for whatever reason) as that "film" is only sometimes countable, and here it isn't.  Hope this helps.